# Bulk insert of devices / measurements

Tags: cumulocity

Do you plan to allow the creation of multiple objects in one only call? For example, currently if I want to create 50 devices (by import), I need to call the API 50 times.

I think it can load the server more unnecessarily that if all objects are contained in the same call.

For a project we don't want to communicate the measurements in real time (every seconds) but postpone the storage in cumulocity. So potentially we need to create ~4000 measurements in one time every hours. Is this approach realistic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sure, there's no problem with this approach. It also permits you to optimise your mobile bandwidth, if you send the data over a mobile data channel. POST a measurement collection instead of a single measurement, i.e., use

```
Content-Type: application/vnd.com.nsn.cumulocity.measurementCollection+json
```

and in the body, use

```
{ "measurements": [ {  ... first measurement ... }, { ... second measurement ... }, ... ] }
```

If you plan to create a large number of measurements at the same time and on a regular base on our public production system, we appreciate an advance note for capacity provisioning.

There's currently no bulk API for creating multiple managed objects in the same call. It's not been a bottleneck for our customers in practical roll-out scenarios.

However, there's an API for bulk registration of devices. Maybe that helps? It's used by the upload button on the device registration page, and is described here: https://cumulocity.com/guides/reference/device-credentials/ ("Bulk device credentials")

Cheers,
André